# Sou cadastrado aqui com o Facebook. Posso vincular meu email?

Tags: suporte, login

Pensei ter perdido a senha do meu SO e quando fui clicar em recuperar, percebi que fiz o cadastro usando o Facebook.

Então me veio em mente a ideia de incluir também o login com email e senha.

É possível ter os dois?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pode ter todas as opções que quiser, sem problemas.

Eu sempre loguei pelo google por uma questão de praticidade, já que ainda dependo dele pra algumas contas de email, mas tenho senha para ocasiões em que a autenticação do google está fora do ar (e já me foi útil mais de uma vez).

Para adicionar novas opções de login, clique no seu ícone de usuário na barra do topo do site. O resto é isso:

> [image: Aba "configurações" > "Meus Log-ins" > "adicionar mais log-ins"]

**NOTA:** O login tradicional, que pede email e senha é a opção "Stack Exchange".

**NOTA 2:** Este mesmo painel permite que você remova algum login que não deseja mais vinculado à sua conta.