# Dependência do facebook na rede

Tags: suporte, login

Esta é uma dúvida que já me surgiu algumas vezes: eu aqui na rede faço login com o facebook, isto porque há 3 anos nunca pensei ser tão ativo e então foi o mais fácil/rápido, decisão de que hoje em dia me arrependo, não gosto de ter a minha conta aqui dependente do facebook.

Então a minha questão é, haverá alguma forma de transferir a minha conta (e tudo o que a ela é adjacente) para uma nova conta independente? Pergunto isto porque se algum dia apagar a minha conta do facebook (para ser sincero esse dia já esteve mais longe), obviamente não gostaria também de perder a minha conta aqui, nem de fazer uma nova e perder tudo o que fiz. Se não existir (como em muitas outras plataformas não existe), não se podia arranjar maneira de implementar isso?

E se existir maneira de criar novas contas, acabei de ver [este link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5559/sou-cadastrado-aqui-com-o-facebook-posso-vincular-meu-email) e realmente testei e dá, mas posso apagar a minha conta do facebook à vontade? Sem que isso não tenha quaisquer consequências aqui na rede?

Comment: Até atualizei a resposta daquela. Você pode tranquilamente criar um login novo e da mesma forma pode usar o painel para remover seu login do Facebook do sistema da rede, antes de deletar a conta (não que seja necessário, mas aí já "limpa" direitinho o vínculo).

Comment: @Bacco obbrigado, entendido, estou mais à vontade agora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, você pode só ir na parte de "[Meus Logins](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current)" do seu perfil e remover a associação com sua conta do Facebook.

Mesmo que você não fizesse nada, sua conta aqui não seria apagada ao apagar a do Facebook. Você só ficaria sem ter como fazer login aqui. Desde que você tenha outra de entrar no SOpt, você pode desassociar (e/ou apagar) seu Facebook sem problemas.

Caso algo dê errado, e você não consiga acessar a conta: [entre em contato com o suporte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) (em português, mesmo) que nós damos um jeito.

Comment: Ok Gabe, muito obrigado, percebido.